# Resizing UISearchBar in UINavigationBar titleView doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift2, uisearchbar

Resizing `UISearchBar` in `UINavigationBar` titleView doesn't work.

[image: UISearchBar]

I also got two navigation items on each side of the `UINavigationBar`.

```
 @IBAction func searchButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {


        searchWrap.frame = self.resultSearchController.searchBar.bounds
        searchWrap .addSubview(self.resultSearchController.searchBar)
        self.resultSearchController.active = true
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.becomeFirstResponder()
        if (UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.Pad)
        {
             self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchWrap
        }
        else
        {
            self.navigationItem.titleView = searchWrap
        }

        searchIsOn = true
        searchButton.hidden = true
        filterButton.hidden = true
        favButtonStar.hidden = true
        settingsButton.hidden = true


    }
```

even if set the frame it automatically resizes.

Comment: can you post the screenshot?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon I have uploaded a screenshot. It seems that although Ian hiding the 4 barbuttonitems (2 on each side) the auto resizing still thinks they are there. There is no way I can override it. By the way I do not want to remove them

Comment: One more thing, are you using `UITableView` and `UISearchBar` separately  and then adding it runtime, right? @George Asda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have created a Demo project for the above solution which you can get it from here.

[Download Demo Project](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=26767144075988912640)

What I have done?

1. First, I added two buttons to `UINavigationBar`. First button is for demo and second is for search.
2. When you tap on search a `UISearchBar` will be added to the `titleView` of `UINavigationBar` and the buttons will be removed from the `UINavigationBar`
3. I have implemented the `cancel` delegate of `UISearchBar`, when it is called I removed `UISearchBar` and added the earlier two buttons again.
4. This how you can get the full `UISearchBar`

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. As I said in my comment on Nov 24th "I do not want to remove them" (the other buttons). I just want to hide them. There is a reason but can't explain that here. Many thanks for your reply though and the time you have spent.

Comment: @GeorgeAsda means that you want that space of the button to be displayed?

Comment: No. As shown on my screen shot I want the search bar to be displayed only, the buttons HIDDEN, but the search bar taking their space too. As if the search bar is overlapping them (but because they're hidden it doesn't matter).

Comment: If you hide the buttons then buttons space will be occupied! That's the reason you can resize the `UISearchBar`. Better option is remove them and make them appear when needed!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not an option (for reasons out of this question's scope). That s why I am puzzled. However I should be able to resize the frame to my liking and override the auto layout. Nothing seems to be working. Trust me I have tried everything and nothing seems to override the auto layout.

Comment: Bro you can't and that's not the AutoLayout issue! It's by default functionality of `UINavigationController`. Example: When you try to put the button on left of `UINavigationBar` and then assign the `UISearchBar` as titleView then the titleView will take the space of 'Right Button' as it is `NIL`.

Comment: So, can't control that too! @GeorgeAsda

Comment: That's so bad. :(     I'll accept your answer as correct although it didn't solve my problem (only because you've spent so much time on this). I'll have to figure out another way.

Comment: Fine, let me know if you find the way! Till then I will be waiting for the updated answer! And Thanks :)

Comment: Vote down for incomplete answer, the answer should be written here

Comment: Please either make the Demo project available again or put code snippets in the answer. As it is now, the answer is pretty much useless.

Answer (score 0):

I have met this issue once. And confirm that `searchBar` that is added as subview on `titleView` does not work. 
`titleView` belongs to `self.navigationController`, and your `searchDelegate` you're using belong to `self` controller, that's not `self.navigationController`. So it can not reach into `delegate` even in debug.

I don't know what your aim, but if you really want to on the `navigationBar`, you could pretend that, make a view look like a `navigationBar`, and add `searchBar` like subview and so on.

Hope this could help.